# PHP Message: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed

Tags: php, apache

I am using this PHP script as a proxy.
The same script on Serer A works with no problem, on a Server B it does not work and I receive these errors:

```
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

and

```
 Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
```

On Server B 
allow_url_fopen = On

is setup

Any idea what could be wrong?

### Thanks

```
<?php
/*
 * in JavaScript call with `encodeURIComponent`
 * $.get('proxy.php?proxy_url='+encodeURIComponent('http://google.com?param=1&param2=2'))
 */
$url = rawurldecode($_GET['proxy_url']);
$cb = ! empty($_GET['callback']) ? $_GET['callback'] : null;

if(preg_match('#ccc\.aaa\.com/bbb/#', $url)){
    $url = preg_replace('#http\://xxx\.xxx\.com/xxx/#', '', $url);
}

if(! preg_match('#^https?:#', $url)){
    $url = preg_replace('#^[\.\/]+#', '', $url);

    if(!file_exists($url)){
        echo 'File not found';
        die(0);
    }
}

if(preg_match('#\.xml$#', $url)){
    header('Content-type: text/xml');
}

$file = file_get_contents($url);

if($cb){
    header('Content-type: application/javascript');
    echo $cb.'('.$file.');';

}else{
    echo $file;
}
```

Comment: code seems ok. did you var_dump'ed your $_GET to see what is incoming. You are not checking the 'proxy_url' sanity before preg_matching it.

Comment: I understand, could be a problem at Server side, some configurations?

Comment: Assuming this is the entry point php file not an include, I really do not know, have you tried ob_start shielding? And If file is parsed first in php 5.4 then exec'd may be you should try adding ?> to the end of your file. A space or cr might be escaping out. I would examine the browser output too.

Comment: Yes it is not an include. Thanks for your suggestions.